# Accessing a dataframe inside functions

Tags: python, dataframe, scope

I'd like to write a module similar to following code. These functions are stored in a separate file.

```
def function_1(arg):
    x1, x2= arg
    x3, x4= dataframe.loc[index, column_list]
    d1, d2 = some computation
    return (d1, d2)

def function_2(arg):
    y1, y2= arg
    y3, y4= dataframe.loc[index, column_list]
    d1, d2= function_1(arg)
    return (a pair of non-linear functions)

def function_3(dataframe):
    data_preprocess
    x, y = fsolve(function_2, initial_values)
    some process
    return (a new dataframe)
```

In the main function, I import this module and then pass the data to `function_3` as follows.

```
dataframe=read_csv(directory)
some data preprocess
dataframe = function_3(dataframe)
```

However, I get following error message:

```
NameError: name 'dataframe' is not defined in 'function_2'
```

Following are my thoughts.

1. Using keyword 'global' in 'function_2' and 'function_1' probably
   won't help, since they will refer to the 'dataframe' in 'main';
2. Keyword 'nonlocal' won't help as well, since it's not written in
   nested way;
3. If adding the dataframe as a parameter, will that affect the 'fsolve'?

Please kindly correct me if I am wrong. And how should I change my code?

Comment: Sorry, I initially misread your question. You are actually spot on in your reasoning. You are just missing the idea of making your own nested scope to work around issue #3. Answer posted.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thank you. It's a very clever idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thoughts are accurate and to the point. You just need one extra step to complete them.Pass in an additional argument to `function2` and wrap the version you pass to `fsolve`, either in a `lambda` or a nested `def` with access to the `function3` namespace:

```
...
def function_2(dataframe, arg):
    ...

def function_3(dataframe):
    # data_preprocess
    x, y = fsolve(lambda arg: function_2(dataframe, arg), initial_values)
    ...

# OR

def function_3(dataframe):
    def fn(arg): return function_2(dataframe, arg)
    # data_preprocess
    x, y = fsolve(fn, initial_values)
    ...
```